# Is leaving property blank same as "all" for transitions?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is the following exactly the same?  If not, what's the difference?

```css
div {
  transition: all 3s;
}
```

vs

```css
div {
  transition: 3s;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are the same:

> Definition and Usage
>
> The **transition-property** property specifies the name of the CSS
>   property the transition effect is for (the transition effect will
>   start when the specified CSS property changes).
>
> Tip: A transition effect could typically occur when a user hover over
>   an element.
>
> Note: Always specify the transition-duration property, otherwise the
>   duration is 0, and the transition will have no effect.
>
> ### Default value: all

Source: 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-property.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's doing the same thing.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1

I changed the css to:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: 3s;
    transition: 3s;
}

.div2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition:all 3s;
    transition:all 3s;
}
```

and added this:

```
<div class="div2"></div>
```

I believe that the default is "all" if you don't specify it but you can target the transition to just a specific property like width, height, font-size, color, etc. I always put "all" though in my code though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equal.

If you don't [declare any value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#declared) and the [cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascade) is empty, the [specified value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#specified) will be the result of the [defaulting](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#defaulting) processes.

> When the [cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascade) does not result in a value, the [specified
>   value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#specified-value) must be found some other way. [Inherited properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherited-property) draw
>   their defaults from their parent element through [inheritance](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inheritance); all
>   other properties take their [initial value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial-value).

Since [`transition-property`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-property-property) is not inheritable, defaulting will yield its [initial value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial-value), which is `all`.